# How can I style a text field in iOS (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextfield

I am a beginner and just started learning iOS. I want to achieve this layout, using Swift:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you drag a text field into your project, there's a number of styling options available in the Utilities bar in Xcode, that can help you style the shape, colour and other properties of your field. To achieve the look you want, you could use something like this:

[image]

Comment: how can I put textfield and button together in a border as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

Place a **UITextField** and a **UIButton** on your story board. Then select both items, and then go to Editor, Embed In, stack view. If they are one on top of the other, change the stack view orientation to vertical then they will be side by side as shown above. Next change the attributes of both in the attributes inspector to taste. You can change the attributes manually in code using `textField.defaultTextAttrubutes = [ "the look you are going for"]`, but you should need to in order to recreate your example.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a view container to your view, inside that container .. add a button and a textfield then add positioning constraints on them.

as you can see in the picture .. it illustrates the idea .. you can style it the way you want e.g. change the height of your textfield .. change its border style etc. the same with your button.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BA8v.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a border, you have to enter some specific information in the attributes inspector. Here is a snapshot of what you can use to create border radius if you want one, vary the thickness of the border, and select a color for the border. [screenshot of attributes inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeThB.png)You can vary the values to make the radius greater and the width thicker also, plus you can change the color. Pay very close attention to the spelling otherwise this won't work.